# Cannot access class varaible withing "findIndex" function - resolved

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, arguments

I cannot access my class variable from *findIndex* method.

```
 My whole class:

    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { History } from '../model/history';
import { SharedService } from "../shared.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  history: History[] = [
    {
      basic_text: { basic_text: 'text_1' },
      summary: { summary: 'summary_1' },
      tager: { tag_algorytm: true, tag_text: "tag_1" }
    },
    {
      basic_text: { basic_text: 'text_2' },
      summary: { summary: 'summary_2' },
      tager: { tag_algorytm: false, tag_text: "tag_2" }
    }
  ];
  basic_text: String = "Tekst podstawowy";
  summary: String = "Streszczenie";
  rating: String = "Ocenione zdania";
  chosedText: string;
  asd: string = 'asdad';

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.sharedMessage.subscribe(chosedText => this.chosedText = chosedText)
  }

  textFilter(h: History[]) {
    let result: History[] = [];
    var param = this.chosedText;
    var foundIndex = h.findIndex(this.isEqualToSelectedText, param);

    result.push(h[foundIndex])
    return result;
  }

  // The function was moved out
  private isEqualToSelectedText(element: History) {
    return element.basic_text.basic_text === this.chosedText;
  }

}
```

I'm assigning thisArg with value of chosedText.
Error that I'm getting:

```
core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'basic_text' of undefined
    at DetailsComponent_tr_12_Template (details.component.html:11)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9274)
    at refreshView (core.js:9143)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10263)
    at refreshView (core.js:9167)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10309)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:8940)
    at refreshView (core.js:9193)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10309)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:8940)
```

But if I do

```
var x= h.findIndex(isEqualToSelectedText, 'text_1');
```

Everything works fine.
I tried to access my class varialb from isEqualToSelectedText function. But I always got this error.
The word "this" should during running of *findIndex* be equal 'text_1'.
Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried ```this.chosedText``` in the last statement? ```element.basic_text.basic_text === this.chosedText```

Comment: Please show us how you are creating the `DetailsComponent` instance and how you are calling the method on it, we can't help you otherwise. It seems you are passing an array that contains `undefined`, not a `History` object.

Comment: @MiguelTrabajo No, that won't work, the `this` argument itself is (supposed to be) a string

Comment: I suppose the actual problem is that you never check whether `foundIndex` is `> -1`, which leads to pushing `undefined` to that `result` array.

Comment: Actually, now I noticed ```this``` will be undefined because of the function scope. He could move the function to a private method in the class

Comment: Hi @Shamer, can you please indent your code sample correctly? It is hard to read as is.

Comment: @EricBurel Hi, I have added it in new comment

Comment: Hi @Shamer, instead you should update the initial question, and remove the comment you have added (answers to questions have to be actual answers, not updates). It's totally fine to update your initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found the error. I was using my variable before it was initialized by "http get".
So the problem is resolved, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

`this` will lose its reference because of the function scope. You could use an arrow function so it can preserve its scope or even move out the `isEqualToSelectedText` function to a private method in that class.

It could be like this:

```js
// in the same place you're declaring the function
const isEqualToSelectedText = (element : History) => {
      return element.basic_text.basic_text === this.chosedText;
}
```

```js
// or moving out to a private method in the class
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    history: History[] = [
        {
            basic_text: { basic_text : 'text_1' },
            summary: { summary : 'summary_1' },
            tager: { tag_algorytm : true, tag_text: 'tag_1' }
        },
        {
            basic_text: { basic_text : 'text_2' },
            summary: { summary : 'summary_2' },
            tager: { tag_algorytm : false, tag_text: 'tag_2' }
        }
    ];

    chosedText: string = 'text_1';

    textFilter(h: History[]) {
        let result: History[] = [];
        var param = this.chosedText;
        var foundIndex= h.findIndex(this.isEqualToSelectedText, param); // <-- changing here

        result.push(h[foundIndex])
        return result;
    }

    // The function was moved out
    private isEqualToSelectedText(element: History) {
        return element.basic_text.basic_text === this.chosedText;
    }
}
```